# Google Hangout button to start a hangout with a particular ID

Tags: button, embed, google-hangouts

I used this developer notes (https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button) on how to embed Start a hangout buttons on my website. But this starts a BLANK hangout where I can add other people.

What I am looking for, is to start a hangout with a particular google ID when I click on that button. Basically, it's like a "Meet Me" shortcut.

Any help on this, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Hangouts API: Can I start an "On Air" Hangout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017657/google-hangouts-api-can-i-start-an-on-air-hangout)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to have the button create a hangout with a particular ID. If it is a Hangout you are in 24/7, you could have the button link to the hangout itself? You can copy the Hangout URL from your address bar when inside.