# Start an Unlisted Google Hangout On Air with a button?

Tags: google-plus

I have a button to start a Hangout On Air, following the examples on this page: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button

But, it seems that when I use a button, the hangout is always publicly listed on my google+ and youtube channels. Can I make a button that will start an unlisted Hangout On Air?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Hangouts API: Can I start an "On Air" Hangout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017657/google-hangouts-api-can-i-start-an-on-air-hangout)

Answer (score 0):

A Hangout on Air is, currently, always public. This is true if you're using the button or not.

To create an unlisted video, you need to go through the YouTube Live startup configuration.

You can, of course, also start a regular (non-On Air) hangout that wouldn't record the video at all. That would be private.

Comment: I think it depends on your definition of "public". I'm asking how to create an **unlisted** hangout such that you would have to explicitly share the link to the HOA, as described here: https://support.google.com/plus/answer/4646402?hl=en.