# Can I create an on-air hangout in the future via google hangout buttons?

Tags: google-hangouts

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button shows how to add a button to my site so I can create an on-air hangout, but what I really want is something like the "Start Hangout On Air" button on https://plus.google.com/hangouts, that lets me choose to have the hangout at a later date.

Is this possible via any API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Hangouts API: Can I start an "On Air" Hangout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017657/google-hangouts-api-can-i-start-an-on-air-hangout)

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time, Ben. You have to use Scheduled Hangout on Air Events to create a future HoA.

Sorry for the bad news.