# How to start and publish On Air Hangout via API

Tags: api, google-plus, google-hangouts, youtube-livestreaming-api, hangouts-api

I want to have "gimme air" slack command that would:

- Create Hangout on Air and make it available for given google domain
- Record it™
- Publish on YouTube as an unlisted video
- Retrieve the link

Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017657/google-hangouts-api-can-i-start-an-on-air-hangout) and [this](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button) question, I can see it's possible to render the button into webpage, but I'd like to get it started automatically.

Is there a way to do that via an API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Hangouts API: Can I start an "On Air" Hangout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017657/google-hangouts-api-can-i-start-an-on-air-hangout)