# how can we create a google hangout on air button with different text?

Tags: google-hangouts

We can see various customization options for the google hangout on air button, changing the widget size appears to change the text, but we'd love to have "Host a hangout on air" rather than "Start a hangout on air".

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#hangout_button_code

Does anyone know if there is a good way to do this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Hangouts API: Can I start an "On Air" Hangout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017657/google-hangouts-api-can-i-start-an-on-air-hangout)