# Start hangout on air private

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I want to start a hangout on air using the hangout button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
        <title>Kicoach</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="placeholder-div4"></div>
        <script>
          gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div4', {
            'render': 'createhangout',
            'hangout_type': 'onair',
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to start it as private, I set my Youtube channel as private but the live alwayrs start as public.
I can't find anymore the documentation for hangout on air button.
Other question, when I start a live, and I go in : https://www.youtube.com/user/USERNAME/live, I can't see my live.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Hangouts API: Can I start an "On Air" Hangout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017657/google-hangouts-api-can-i-start-an-on-air-hangout)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Probando google hangout button</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
 <div class="g-hangout" data-render="createhangout" data-hangout_type="onair"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain as well in the answer.